# Understanding how R stores SQLlite databases

Tags: r, database, sqlite, dplyr, dbplyr

Playing with databases in R I observed the following case:

```
library(dplyr)
library(RSQLite)
library(dbplyr)

## Creating data
d <- data.frame(x=1:100)

## Setting up a sqlite database
dv <- dbDriver("SQLite")
con <- dbConnect(dv, dbname="test.db")

## Writing the data to the db
dbWriteTable(con, "data", d,header=T)

## Reading the data back
d.tbl = tbl(con,"data" )

## Apply a filter and collect the data
d.tbl <- d.tbl %>% filter(x<5)
d.coll <- collect(d.tbl)

## Save the filtered data into another database
con2 <- dbConnect(dv, dbname="test2.db")
dbWriteTable(con2, "data", d.coll, header=T)

## Reading it again to make sure the filter was applied
dx1 <- dbReadTable(con, "data")
dx2 <- dbReadTable(con2, "data")
```

Works like a charm. 
Looking at the two db files produced I saw:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 mycomp  staff        2048 19 Oct 23:24 test.db
-rw-r--r--   1 mycomp  staff        2048 19 Oct 23:24 test2.db
```

they have exactly the same size...
Even if test2.db contains the full data plus the query, it has at least the query in addition to test.db. And I made sure that the filter had been applied.

Any enlightment?